# crystal report 13 - after hosting in arvixe print option is not working

Tags: asp.net, iis, crystal-reports, activex

I am using visual studio 2013 and crystal report 13. The print option was working when i hosted locally in IIS express. In IE printing was coming and in Chrome and Firefox export to pdf was working fine. But I hosted i on arvixe hosting. After that the print option or export are not at all working in any browser. Do I need to do any settings?

And in my local computer after hosting also in IE, Printing is working. But not in any other systems.

So my question is do we need to do any settings in IE for this or any alternatives.

Please help

Comment: Have you ask them to setup Crystal Report? Does your plan come with Crystal report support?

Comment: They suggested that crystal report is already included but they dont provide support for it. My plan have crystal report. Only printing is having problem. Report is appearing

Comment: Can anyone please give a solution